# syslog-ng return original value when mapping does not exists

Tags: syslog, syslog-ng

i'm using syslog-ng for collecting json messages and send alarms to slack

there is parameter in json message which contains IP address of router from which I'm receiving the json message and I want to convert IP address to router hostname

i'm using two parsers 1) parse json 2) replace IP address with router hostname:

```json
parser p_json {
    json-parser(prefix(".json."));
};

parser p_acd_router {
    add-contextual-data(selector("${.json.router_ip}"), database("host_map.csv"), prefix(".meta_router."));
};
```

until now everything works fine.
Hi,
I'm having the problem when I receive log message from router and I don't have IP_to_Hostname mapping for it in csv file. in this case i just get blank space in syslog message. there is option to return default value if mapping does not exist, but i would prefer to return original value (IP address)

if mapping exists convert IP address to hostname >> works
if mapping does not exist, return original IP address >> don't know how to set it up

is this even supported?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `default-selector("UNKNOWN")` option for `add-contextual-data()`, and add a record to your CSV file with the ID `UNKNOWN`, and use the following value when setting `.meta_router.hostname`: `${.json.router_ip}`.

TLDR: templates are supported inside the CSV file as well.

---

Note: In case your IPs are reverse-resolvable, you can just use the `$(dns-resolve-ip)` template function instead of maintaining a complete CSV database:

https://github.com/syslog-ng/syslog-ng/pull/3046

Comment: perfect, thanks! (IPs are not resolvable in this case so 1st solution was needed)